# Close SMS inapp window iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, sms

I have an app that have an sendInAppSMS action inside it. It brings up a window with a pre entered body in the message. Problem is that pressing the cancel button doesn't work. If I press send it sends the message but doesn't close the window. So I have to close the app completely to get rid of it.

Someone out there who might have run in to this before? Tried to search here but couldn't find a solution..

Cheers!

This is how my code looks like:

```
-(IBAction) sendInAppSMS:(id) sender
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        CLLocation *location=[self findCurrentLocation];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinae=[location coordinate];
        controller.body =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" Alarm!, call the senders number with latitude:%f longitude:%f",coordinae.latitude,coordinae.longitude]; ;
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"phonenumber1", @"phonenumber2", nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

I'm learning by doing, so I don't expect answers but if you feel to help out, where do I put that it in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set up and implement MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate? Try this

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result{   
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**Edit:**
To set delegate:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *myComposer = [MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
myComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self;
```

Comment: Sorry for being such a n00b, and I don't expect an answer but can't find out where to put that code (keep in mind I am a designer just started to learn programming apps and are still reading my first book) :P

Comment: Solved it! Thanks!  Had the right code, just missing controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;  works great now!